# Garbage Collector, call & callvirt and Debug/Release code mode execution differences

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public int I;

    public SomeClass(int input) {
        I = input;
        Console.WriteLine("I = {0}", I);
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
        Console.WriteLine("deleted");
    }

    public void Foo() {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

and this program:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Thread(() => {
                       Thread.Sleep(100);
                       GC.Collect();
                   }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

        new SomeClass(10).Foo();

        // The same as upper code
        // var t = new SomeClass(10);
        // t.Foo();
    }
}
```

When i run this code in **Debug mode**, i have next result:

```
I = 10
Foo
deleted
```

but, when i change mode to **Release**, result changes to:

```
I = 10
deleted
Foo
```

As i understand, there is difference with `call` and `callvirt`: when optimization starts in **Release** mode, compiler look at `Foo` method and can't find any reference to `SomeClass` in this method, and that's why this method calls as static method by address, and **garbage collector** could collect this object.

Otherwise, if i change `Foo` method (for example, add `Console.WriteLine(I)` into this method), compiler won't decide to call this method as `call` and it should be called by pointer to instance with `callvirt` and **garbage collector** won't collect this object.

Can you please explain more clearly, what's going on here (why **GC** could collect object and if it's so, how does method calls).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that it's really anything to do with `call` and `callvirt`.

I strongly suspect it's simply because you're not using any fields within `SomeClass.Foo`. The garbage collector is free to collect an object when it is certain that none of the data will be referenced again - so no code is going to look at any references to the object, or any fields within the object.

Basically, if you write a finalizer and you need to ensure that the object isn't finalized while methods within that object are running, you need to be *very* careful. You can use `GC.KeepAlive(this)` at the end of methods, as one approach, but it's a bit ugly. I would personally try very hard to avoid needing a finalizer at all, if you can. I can't remember the last time I wrote one. (See [Joe Duffy's blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/) for more.)

When there's a debugger attached, the GC is *much* less aggressive about what it can collect - after all, if you can break into the debugger at any point and inspect the fields of any object that is the target of a running instance method, that removes the possibility of garbage collecting those objects.

Comment: If i understand you right, garbage collector inspect references in code, which will execute later. So, there should be graph of references and dependencies of executing code (or all compiled program?). And if it's so, how does this graph build, and what time? Does analyze of references and dependencies executes ones when program compiling, or each time when garbage collector run? Ty.

Comment: @FSou1 - I've found an old MS presentation and added it to my answer - it shows how the JIT and GC work together to track references.

Comment: @FSou1: I *suspect* the JIT compiler notices the last point in each method where variables are "live" - but that's all an implementation detail which really shouldn't affect your code.

Comment: Yeah, i've just found answer in CLR via C#, ty for answer ;)

Comment: @FSou1: Just be aware that any *implementation details* found in a book may well be out of date by the time you read them :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're debugging, the whole system<sup>1</sup> extends the lifetime of objects beyond their natural lifetime.

So, when a thread is executing this method:

```
public void Foo() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}
```

This method makes no use of `this`. So when not debugging, after this method has started running, it doesn't require the object to exist any longer.

However, when debugging, you might have set a breakpoint on that `Console.WrtieLine` method, and from there decide to inspect `this`. So the system conspires to keep `this` alive (as well as any local variables which are no longer used within the body of a method).

---

<sup>1</sup>This old [presentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/1/e216b4ce-1417-41af-863d-ec15f2d31b59/DEV490.ppt) shows how the JIT and GC actually work together to work out which references are live (see slide 30 onwards). It is my understanding that the JIT does more work to help out with debugging - by not reusing local variable slots which it could (so values are still visible) and by informing the GC that all variables are alive throughout the method, rather than the more piecemeal analysis it can provide.

Comment: Can you please explain a little, slide "Roots and GC preparation"- this table, where are offsets and roots,- each row of this table is an operator in method?

Comment: I've just loot at CLR via C# and found this table and all processing actions. Ty a lot for presentation and answer! ;)

Comment: @FSou1 - each row of that table is describing a range of the method's compiled code, and which variables are alive if the processor's instruction pointer is currently in that range.